# How I can make SQLite Database Central on App Store?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.0

HI, I am new to Iphone app development. I am suppose to develop an app which will have central database like we have in any .Net web Application. Do SQLite provide such feature and if yes, where i have to put my database so that different users can access same database from their Apps.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No SQLite is only to store things on each individual phone. I would use a central server with a web-service interface (and your favorite SQL or noSQL server as its backing store) that is accessed by the iPhone application.

Also SQLite does not scale well when many users are performing concurrent inserts - it is not that kind of a database. Use something like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle or whatever that is designed for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks mrz for replying. Do App store accept that logic while accepting App. One more thing , can we upload Enterprise based Iphone apps and put them on App store so that Enterprise users can only access that app from App store.